# All permutations with replacement in Julia

Tags: julia, combinatorics

Suppose there are only 3 students. Let R and G be the colors of uniforms a student can have. Let S be the set of colors(permutations) that students wear in a particular day. How can I generate the sample space in Julia?

S = {RRR,RRG,RGR,RGG,GRR,GRG,GGR,GGG}

```
using Combinatorics
colors = ['R','G']
n = 3
b = permutations(colors,n)
 for a in b
       print(a)
       end
```

is not giving anything.

Ref : [How to generate all permutations of an array in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687229/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-an-array-in-julia)

[Julia: Unique sets of n elements with replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313868/julia-unique-sets-of-n-elements-with-replacement) is related but not clearly solves the problem

Comment: Vinod the issue is that permutations is grabbing items without replacement. You want it to be with replacement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Julia: Unique sets of n elements with replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313868/julia-unique-sets-of-n-elements-with-replacement)

Comment: @Mark 4-element Vector{String}:
 "RRR"
 "RRG"
 "RGG"
 "GGG". I need permutations, not combinations.

Comment: @Mark. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313868/julia-unique-sets-of-n-elements-with-replacement does not answer my qn

Comment: apologies, I overlooked the bit where that function was getting combinations, not permutations

Comment: that question, if you scroll down, has the answer: `Iterators.product`. The answer in this case is `Iterators.product(colors, colors, colors) |> collect`

Comment: or `Iterators.product(fill(colors, n)...) |> collect`

Comment: @Mark Iterators.product is depracated?

Comment: Vinod where does it say that?

Comment: help?> product                                              
                         
                                                            
  No documentation found.                                   
                                                            
  IterTools.product is a Function.                          
                                                            
  # 1 method for generic function "product" from IterTools: 
   [1] product(xss...)                                      
       @ deprecated.jl:103

Comment: oh right, use IterTools

Comment: for future people: https://juliapackages.com/p/iterators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is equivalent to the product of the colors vector with itself three times:

```
using IterTools 

IterTools.product(colors, colors, colors) |> collect

# or 

IterTools.product(fill(colors, n)...) |> collect
```

Output:

```
2×2×2 Array{Tuple{Char, Char, Char}, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 ('R', 'R', 'R')  ('R', 'G', 'R')
 ('G', 'R', 'R')  ('G', 'G', 'R')

[:, :, 2] =
 ('R', 'R', 'G')  ('R', 'G', 'G')
 ('G', 'R', 'G')  ('G', 'G', 'G')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of doing it with `Combinatorics`:

```
julia> reduce(vcat, collect(multiset_permutations(x, 3)) for x ∈ with_replacement_combinations(["R", "G"], 3))
8-element Vector{Vector{String}}:
 ["R", "R", "R"]
 ["R", "R", "G"]
 ["R", "G", "R"]
 ["G", "R", "R"]
 ["R", "G", "G"]
 ["G", "R", "G"]
 ["G", "G", "R"]
 ["G", "G", "G"]
```

Answer (score 2):

For variety, here is a one-liner which does something similar:

```
getindex.("RG", collect.(Tuple.(CartesianIndices((2,2,2)))))
```

or, to print them as well:

```
julia> println.(getindex.("RG", collect.(Tuple.(CartesianIndices((2,2,2))))));
RRR
GRR
RGR
GGR
RRG
GRG
RGG
GGG
```

Comment: what is this doing? I love it but I'm unsure what precisely it is doing

Comment: `CartesianIndices((2,2,2))` is all the ways to address a 2x2x2 tensor. For example in position 1,2,1. `collect.(Tuple.())` turns this into a vector `[1,2,1]` (again applies to all possible indices by broadcasting). `"RG"[[1,2,1]]` which is the same as `getindex("RG", [1,2,1])` builds a string from locations 1,2,1 in "RG" which gives "RGR". With broadcasting, you get the desired result.